# Question for complicated custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I found some interesting articles about custom function which use conditional structure. For example,

```
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.greater(y_T,y_P),(y_T-y_P)/a,(y_T-y_P)*b))
```

That is imporessed me. The basic learning process for deep learning depends on BP. Could tensorflow accomplish such complicate BP process? It is hard for me to image how to BP this function and ensure the efficiency. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but it needs to be a function, not variable
you can have a custome loss function like this:

```
def cust_func(a, b):
    def cust_loss_inner(y_T, y_P):
        y_T, y_P = tf.dtypes.cast(y_T, tf.float32), tf.dtypes.cast(y_P, tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.greater(y_T, y_P), (y_T - y_P) / a, (y_T - y_P) * b))
    return cust_loss_inner
```

you can also choose to cast y_T, y_P to float64 or others, but they must have the same type.

to use the above loss, you can compile with the below code, 3 and 4 correspond to a and b values you want.

```
model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER,
                  loss=cust_func(3, 4),
                  metrics=METRICS)
```